# How to invoke SignalR Hub from WCF Service

Tags: wcf, signalr, firebase-cloud-messaging, signalr-hub, sqldependency

Hi I have 2 projects the first one is SignalR Hub
and the 2nd project is WCF Service (which should invoke SignalR Hub)
(both projects are located in the same server)

I need to find a way to automatically invoke the SignalR Hub on WCF Project Start but since WCF services is an on-request service then it will not fire the invoke until a request happen from clients connected to it.

my idea is as following (if you have any better suggests please let me know)
I have a table in a databases
the table will include notifications which will get inserted automatically by a trigger located in another table (operations table)

the idea of using signalR project is to detect each insert in Notifications Table using SignalR with SQLDependency and ServiceBroker

now when the SignalR detects any insert it will fire an FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) notifications and the clients will receive the notifications

I have used the FCM becuase it supports multiple platforms and it is easy to deploy it.

Comment: SQLDependency is not connected to SignalR. You implement the SQLDependency functionality in your WCF project, then fire your FCM notification. Now, SignalR could be used to notify your clients, but this is a completely separate requirement.

Comment: Ah so I guess in my requirement i don't need to use SignalR because SQLDependency can do the job of detecting changes in the table and it will invoke an onchange event when a change happens?

Comment: Correct. That's what SQLDependency does, you hook up events that will fire in C# in response to changes in your database to the table in question. It actually creates dynamic Service Broker queues in the database to enable this.

Comment: @reckface your comments answered my question. would you please post it as an answer so i can accept it ! 

I added a SQLCommand and set its command text to "SELECT * FROM NotificationsTbl" then I assigned this SQLcommand to a SQLDependency (of course after enabling Service Broker), now when ever a change happen in NotificationsTbl the SQLDependency will detect it and will fire the OnChange Event, in the OnChange event I fire FCM notifications while will notify the clients about a change.

Comment: Now I don't need the SignalR because FCM will do the job (notifying clients)